# TFTP where did my file go?

Tags: windows-7, linux, file-transfer, tftp

I got a TFTP server working on my windows 7 machine, and attempted to send a text file over to my uCLinux board.

```
C:\Users\me>Tftp localhost PUT p4tickets.txt 192.168.254.1
Transfer successful: 63 bytes in 1 second(s), 63 bytes/s
```

So it sounds like it went successfully, but when I go and check the device (I did a `ls -R` from root) I'm not seeing the `p4tickets.txt` file anywhere... If the file went successfully, where did it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your command syntax documentation, and check your Windows machine.  You might have done a file transfer from your Windows machine ***to your Windows machine*** and created a file called `192.168.254.1`.

Comment: ...yup, there's a file with the IP address name

Answer (score 0):

It went to wherever the root of the TFTP server is set to (this is not necessarily `/`, it might be `/var/tftp/` or somewhere else). Your best bet would be to check the configuration for the TFTP server to see what location is configured as the root.

Comment: The TFTP server's configuration determines where the file will end up on the client?  (So in my case, the Windows config will tell me where it will go on the uCLinux side?)

Comment: `tftp` is the client program. There is a server program running on the uCLinux device. You will need to look at the configuration for the tftp server on the uCLinux device.